# Is it possible to specify physical name for database?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to specify the physical file name for creating a database with a different database name in EF Code First WPF application??

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it once you are using a connection string:

```
var source ="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
    AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|FileName.mdf"
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#attachdbfilename

To use a connection string with EF see http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx under "ConnectionString Name"